# Как спозиционировать блоки в зависимости от условий?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, позиционирование

Есть блок в котором 4 `span` и картинка. 2 `span` с классами `abs` и картинка постоянные, а 2 `span` с классом `rel` могут как присутствовать, так и нет, причем расположение картинки не должно поменяться от этого (не должна смещаться!) и если нет блока `rel-1` - `rel-2` должен переместиться на его место. Если же нет обоих блоков `rel`, то картинка уезжает наверх `margin-top:-50px;` и в этом основная проблема. Как это можно сделать стилями или без скриптов никак? вот [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/nzwhkzsw/2/)

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}
img {
  margin-top:-50px;
}
.rel {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.abs-1,
.abs-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.abs-1 {
  right: 0;
}
.abs-2 {
  right: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="rel">rel-1</span>
  <span class="rel">rel-2</span>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <span class="abs-1">abs-3</span>
  <span class="abs-2">abs-4</span>
</div>
```

з.ы. в реальном примере таких блоков много и картинка подгружается динамически, поэтому ее нельзя накладывать на **div**  + ее размеры (высота) может меняться и под ней расположены еще блоки

Comment: как вы генерируете `<span class="rel">rel-1</span>`?

Comment: @Grundy динамически из бд подтягивается

Comment: как они генерируются в html?

Comment: @Grundy `<?php $data = get_the_ID(); ?> <span <?php echo "data-id=" . $data; ?> class='quick-view'></span>`

Comment: И это все в цикле по какому-то массиву, так?

Comment: @Grundy да, все правильно

Comment: Тогда проще всего проверить, что в этом массиве есть элементы, если есть - оставлять margin:-50px; если нет - ставить класс на img - в котором будет margin:0; и все никаких скриптов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Вместо отрицательного маржина дать картинке абсолютное позиционирование по левому верхнему углу родителя и z-index. А блокам - z-index побольше.

Недостаток - за картинкой идёт текст. Если она позиционируется абсолютно, текст попадает под картинку.

Вариант 2. Завернуть оба rel в div, и абсолютно позиционировать этот div. Картинку поставить первой и её стили вообще не понадобятся.

```css
.main {
  position:relative;
  width:350px;
  height:150px;
}
.box {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.rel {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
.abs-1, .abs-2 {
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
.abs-1 {
  right:0;
}
.abs-2 {
  right:55px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<div class="box">
<span class="rel">rel-1</span>
<span class="rel">rel-2</span>
</div>
<span class="abs-1">abs-3</span>
<span class="abs-2">abs-4</span>
<p>какой-то текст</p>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но еще 1 важное дополнение: размеры (высота) картинки может меняться и под ней расположены еще блоки https://jsfiddle.net/nzwhkzsw/2/ - мой косяк, что это сразу не указал, сорри..

Comment: @Вася Вариант: завернуть rel в div, и абсолютно позиционировать этот div. Картинку поставить первой и её стили вообще не понадобятся. Сейчас переделаю ответ.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, для второго случая z-index уже не нужно выставлять

Comment: @Grundy Да, спасибо. Это от первой версии осталось. Почистил.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - позиционировать картинку абсолютно, тогда margin - не нужен, и наличие/отсутствие блоков не будет влиять на расположение картинки.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
}
.rel {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.abs-1,
.abs-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.abs-1 {
  right: 0;
}
.abs-2 {
  right: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="rel">rel-1</span>
  <span class="rel">rel-2</span> 
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <span class="abs-1">abs-3</span>
  <span class="abs-2">abs-4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но еще 1 важное дополнение: размеры (высота) картинки может меняться и под ней расположены еще блоки https://jsfiddle.net/nzwhkzsw/2/ - мой косяк, что это сразу не указал, сорри..